# Correcting misspelled bash commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm looking for a way to correct bash commands if they have been misspelled.

Let's say you have installed a program called "FooBar" but you type "foobar" (or foo bar or FOOBAR or foebar) in your shell. Is there any way to check if something similar to what you are looking for exists in your PATH?

I'm thinking about writing a bash script that normalizes user input and uses the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to check what they have typed against anything in PATH. But maybe there's already something is written out there or a better way to accomplish this task.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's probably already a solution to this, try migrating the question to superuser.com.

Comment: The downvote is because this questions shouldn't be here or for another reason?

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but how would you integrate it into your shell? Should it automatically execute what it *thinks* you meant? For an input `mr` the Levenshtein distance is the same to both `mv` and `rm`!

Comment: I think you must decide whether you want a working solution (which is off topic for SO) or you want to write it yourself anyway. And I think it would be an interesting exercise. Are you limited to bash?

Comment: On ubuntu it does it by default. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/197633/any-way-to-list-similar-commands

Comment: @Jongware, I just want to print the best alternative if the written command doesn't exist. I'm thinking to consider as good alternatives any command with a  Levenshtein distance of 20% user input rounded down. So any command with less than 5 characters need a Levenshtein distance == 0 to be chosen. And no, I'm not limited to bash. Any script language is good.

Comment: @user000001 Cool! It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but it's a good starting point. I'm using Debian, but I guess I can reuse that python script. Well, if the bash script i'm making doesn't work, I'll go in this direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you problem is case-sensitivity only, then you can switch this off in the readline configuration by the following:

```
echo "set completion-ignore-case On" >> ~/.inputrc
```

However, if you are seeking for some clever mechanism to execute *similar* commands (by using fuzzy logic for example) I'll not recommend to use such tool in a command-line since it could be very dangerous.

Imagine what could happen for example in commands like *rmv*? is it rm or mv? .. only the user can answer this question.

**Note**:  This may be useful if you are running a Cygwin env where case-sensitivity is not a problem. In Linux commands are case sensitive. So switching this functionality off is not a good idea.

Comment: Case-sensitive is not the (only) problem and I don't want to autocorrect the command, just print the best alternative to let the user know how it's written. Anyway, +1 for coming out with this original fix for the case-sensitive "problem".